# How Can I Get Value_Type on both value and pointer by using template in c++?

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits, concept

```
template<class T>
    struct TypeInfo {
        using value_type = is_pointer<T>::value ? T * : T;
    };
```

This code is just pseudocode. I wanna find value type for each pointer and value.
I'll using this like `sizeof(TypeInfo<something>::value_type )`. Can you help me?

Comment: Could you please clarify what output you would expect? Should `TypeInfo<int *>::value_type` really be `int**`? Or do you want to remove the pointer? It the latter case: How do you want to handle multiple pointers like `int **`? Should it become `int` or just `int *`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
template<class T>
struct TypeInfo {
    using value_type = std::remove_pointer_t<T>;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
template<class T>
auto consteval _GetValueType()
{
    if constexpr (is_pointer<T>()) {
        return _GetValueType<remove_pointer_t<T>>();
    }
    else {
        return T();
    }
}

template<class T>
struct  GetValueType
{
    using value_type = decltype(_GetValueType<T>());
};
```

this work for any [(\*)*]classes.